# RAM usage is high altough there is no high usage from proccesses?

Tags: virtual-machines, memory, centos6, memory-usage, buffer

Our virtual server has Centos 6 OS.

When I look to buffer/cache usage it seems less at first line. Proccesses're not use to memory highly. Do u have any idea about this situation? Can it be about buffer/cache usage(like second line), do we have any way to limit buffer ? How can i decrease usage of memory ?

```
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           15G        15G       211M       404K       138M       303M
-/+ buffers/cache:        14G       653M
Swap:         3.9G       107M       3.8G


top - 05:29:39 up 62 days, 19:22,  1 user,  load average: 0.07, 0.03, 0.00
Tasks: 232 total,   2 running, 230 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.4%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16333568k total, 16081072k used,   252496k free,   141552k buffers
Swap:  4063228k total,   110864k used,  3952364k free,   311512k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1871 root      20   0  472m 9480 5128 S  2.0  0.1   1889:02 BESClient
 2977 root      20   0 17.2g 674m  11m S  1.0  4.2  13:56.98 java
   23 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0 161:15.05 migration/5
 2616 root      20   0  312m 3872 2380 S  0.3  0.0 105:57.95 python
 6073 root      20   0 15184 1396  972 R  0.3  0.0   0:00.01 top
    1 root      20   0 19232 1044  856 S  0.0  0.0   5:24.30 init
```

Thanks for your helping....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from [this](https://raj2796.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/reducing-cached-memory-usage-linux-high-memory-usage-diagnosing-and-troubleshooting-on-vmware-and-out-of-memory-oom-killer-problem-and-solution/) article. Problem was caused from java max min variables.

```
ps -ef | grep java
root      2977     1  0 Mar21 ?        00:14:16 /opt/open/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/open/stm/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms1024m -Xmx13312m -Xrs -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.open.configFile=collector.xml -Dcom.open.home=/opt/open -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/open/stm/etc/properties/….
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice explanation is [here](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/). In short, if you have free memory, system use memory as disk cache, but when some program wants RAM, this cache contetn is freed and RAM is available